# Adding peer to a existing network in hyperledger v1.0 from a different machine

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I followed the link below to setup a Hyperledger Fabric
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

I see the two orgs and two peers running in the same machine. 
I wanted to add another peer to this already setup network.
Requesting some help here as to what steps i should follow to get this thing done.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `docker-compose-cli.yaml` file, and restart the docker-compose. There, you have to add and define a new Peer.

Then, you should execute the `CHANNEL_NAME=$CHANNEL_NAME TIMEOUT=<pick_a_value> docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d` command (again). With that command, I think that you will maintain the previous Docker containers and a new one will create for your network.

Comment: What i did i kept one orderer and two peers of org1 on one machine and one orderer and two peer of org2 on another machine. i was able to communicate.

Comment: But the issue  is that wen i invoke the chain code pointing to one machine orderer i dont see the change happening on peer of the other machines.  what concept am i missing here. i thought the change will reflect in all peers.
` peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'echo $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH`

Comment: How did you define the channel?! Which members take part on it?! Both Orderers and all the Peers? Also, in the definition of each docker-compose.yaml file, you have to define network_mode: host for all the containers of Docker

Comment: channel was defined using 
`peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem`

where CHANNEL_NAME is mychannel
then i joined all the 4 peers(two of org1 m/c1 and two of org2 m/c2) but when i execute the "invoke","a","b","10" on machine on1 i cant see the change on the peer of the machine2. one orderer is also there on machine2. is it the issue?

Comment: How do you define the creation of each container (in the docker-compose.yaml files)? Do you define the network_mode: host for each container? On the other hand, could you get the logs from each machine? And for each node? I suggest you to open a new question.

Comment: Updated the detail in the rocket chat. please check .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you would like to span multi host deployment, you might consider to use:

1. [Fabric deploy script](https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment)
2. [Ansible playbook](https://github.com/keoja/hyperledger-ansible)

Apart from this you can join remote peer simply by using peer cli tool (assuming you'd like to add peer from allowed organization).

1. First of all you need to fetch config block by:

   peer channel fetch config -o orderer:7050 -c mychannel
2. Next join peer using config block:

   peer channel join -o orderer:7050 --blockpath mychannel.block